# IIS Permission, DNS resolution issues

Tags: iis

Trying to get an internal website up, but having 2 errors.

1st error is that the site "can't be found", fix your DNS yadda yadda. NSlookup finds the proper IP just fine, I can ping it by the name, everything seems to be in order, but when I put it in the address bar of the browser, error every time.

2nd error is that if I try to access the site via IP in the address bar instead of the name, I get an "access denied" error. Note that this is not a 403 error; It doesn't even get that far. Error states "you are not allowed to access the document at location *address*.

Been poking at this for nearly 2 days, and I can't figure out where the problem is for the life of me.

Comment: From where do you get the errors? a client machine or the server itself?

Comment: What is the exact first error? Do you get an HTTP error code like 401, 404, 403, etc? If so, what is the error code? Sounds like you might have host headers configured. Check that and update the question with whether that's true or not.

Comment: Please state from where you tested, as often ISP modem block incoming connection to the port 80/443, or your router do have console on those port.

Comment: I've tested from both the IIS server, as well as a server 2U above it and my laptop.

Error is: Unknown Host

 "Description: Unable to locate the server named "testapp.test.local" --- the server does not have a DNS entry. Perhaps there is a misspelling in the server name, or the server no longer exists. Double-check the name and try again." Note that NSlookup resolves the name correctly.

ISP is irrelevant in this case, the connection never leaves the rack.

Comment: Are you using SSL/HTTPS? What browser are you using, Chrome? Did you have a chance to check the host headers configuration?

Comment: Plain HTTP. Using IE 11.x, the default on Win10 and server 16. I'm not seeing where a host headers configuration would be, is that the same as the configured host name?

Comment: Can you include details of your IIS setup - What sites do you have? What hostname & ports are bound to each site? Where are your sites webroots? Also repeat your test and try to access the app locally and remotely for both IP and domain name then check all recent logs under `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC...` and post any entries related to the test.  Sounds like you have routing/dns and permission issues.

Comment: Another thought if your IIS is *not* domain joined you could override DNS locally by adding `127.0.0.1 testapp.test.local` to your IIS servers hosts file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) using notepad - `testapp.test.local` should then resolve from the IIS server(only). I expect this will still return an error page, but at least proves IIS is handling traffic by name & IP.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Run the report and it should help diagnose the first issue. For the second one, you can only check IIS log files to see what's the sub status, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0